# min width with BS3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, width

I have a website, that uses BS3 responsive design to adjust to the device size. Due to some of components used in the site, the BS panels overlap on smaller screens. To facilitate best viewing experience of those components, I need to make the site to show at a minimum width. A horizontal scroll is OK.

I tried to set the min-width of body, div etc. But none seems to override responsiveness of the BS.

Is there a way to achieve this with minimal css changes and not changing every BS3 class usage in the site.

Answer (score 0):

The following recipe may do the job:

1. Make sure your  bootstrap html is wrapped by `<div class="container">`.
2. Set `min-width` in css, like:

   .container {
       min-width: 800px;
   }
3. To avoid collapse of columns in lower resolutions, replace all `col-**-nn` classes in the html by `col-xs-nn`. For example, replace `<div class="col-md-3">` by `<div class="col-xs-3">`.

See [example](http://jsbin.com/ruduho/6/edit?html,css,output)